# Pushing siblings together in tikz tree

Tags: tikz-qtree

I tried several approaches, but none of them worked...
Here is my tree code:

```
\begin{figure}[bh!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[ level distance=1cm, growth parent anchor=east, grow=right,scale=0.78, 
level distance=1cm,
]

\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\footnotesize, text width=5mm,anchor=east]

\Tree[.{0} [.{1} [.{1} [.{1} [.{1} [.{2} [.{7} [.{9} [.{4} [.{33} ] [.{474} ] ] [.{478} ] ] [.{487} ] ] [.{494} ] ] [.{496} ] ] [.{497} ] ] [.{498} ] ] [.{499} ] ] [.{4} [.{13} [.{4} [.{4} [.{7} [.{25} [.{9} [.{120} [.{314} ] [.{314} ] ] [.{434} ] ] [.{443} ] ] [.{468} ] ] [.{475} ] ] [.{479} ] ] [.{483} ] ] [.{496} ] ] [.{1} [.{2} [.{18} [.{39} [.{2} [.{55} [.{56} [.{327} ] [.{327} ] ] [.{383} ] ] [.{438} ] ] [.{440} ] ] [.{479} ] ] [.{497} ] ] [.{499} ] ] [.{3} [.{10} [.{2} [.{3} [.{6} [.{8} [.{7} [.{16} [.{32} ] [.{445} ] ] [.{461} ] ] [.{468} ] ] [.{476} ] ] [.{482} ] ] [.{485} ] ] [.{487} ] ] [.{497} ] ] [.{6} [.{9} [.{7} [.{1} [.{3} [.{3} [.{9} [.{14} [.{24} ] [.{448} ] ] [.{462} ] ] [.{471} ] ] [.{474} ] ] [.{477} ] ] [.{478} ] ] [.{485} ] ] [.{494} ] ] [.{444} [.{56} ] [.{56} ] ] ]

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

and here is how it looks like:

[image]

I want it to be narrower, i.e., pushing together the siblings at level one so there is no free space between the branches - or at least a bit less space...

Comment: You have to watch for the space between 24 and 497. That is the actual space even if zero it. So you can go to negative numbers for a little tighter spacing. But then 444 branch will be overlapping. You might better reduce the sibling distance of the inbetween leaves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no pretty way to do this, since `tikz-qtree` is designed to automatically make enough space for the complete width of the daughters of any particular node.  As percusse points out in the comments, if you reduce the sibling distance, you end up with your 444 node overlapping the others.  This is what needs to be avoided.  We can do this by adding specific node sizes to certain nodes, and making the level 1 sibling distance negative. The one downside to this is that the bounding box of the picture is artificially large, so we need to manually adjust the bounding box.

I also removed the fixed `text width` which makes the trees look neater, and changed your `\tikzstyle` command for `\tikzset`.  See [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/2693) for some discussion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm, growth parent anchor=east,
  grow=right,scale=0.78,level distance=1cm,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=-2.25cm}
]

\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\footnotesize,anchor=east}}


\useasboundingbox (-.5cm,-9cm) rectangle (10cm,6cm);

\Tree[.{0}  [.{1} [.{1} [.{1} [.{1} [.{2} [.{7} [.{9} [.{4} [.{33} ] [.{474} ] ] [.{478} ] ] [.{487} ] ] [.{494} ] ] [.{496} ] ] [.{497} ] ] [.{498} ] ] [.{499} ] ]
   [.\node[minimum height=2.25cm] (4) {4}; [.{13} [.{4} [.{4} [.{7} [.{25} [.{9} [.{120} [.{314} ] [.{314} ] ] [.{434} ] ] [.{443} ] ] [.{468} ] ] [.{475} ] ] [.{479} ] ] [.{483} ] ] [.{496} ] ] 
   [.\node[minimum height=1.5cm] (1) {1}; [.{2} [.{18} [.{39} [.{2} [.{55} [.{56} [.{327} ] [.{327} ] ] [.{383} ] ] [.{438} ] ] [.{440} ] ] [.{479} ] ] [.{497} ] ] [.{499} ] ] 
   [.{3} [.{10} [.{2} [.{3} [.{6} [.{8} [.{7} [.{16} [.{32} ] [.{445} ] ] [.{461} ] ] [.{468} ] ] [.{476} ] ] [.{482} ] ] [.{485} ] ] [.{487} ] ] [.{497} ] ] 
   [.{6} [.{9} [.{7} [.{1} [.{3} [.{3} [.{9} [.{14} [.{24} ] [.{448} ] ] [.{462} ] ] [.{471} ] ] [.{474} ] ] [.{477} ] ] [.{478} ] ] [.{485} ] ] [.{494} ] ] 
   [.\node[minimum height=6.5cm] (444) {444}; [.{56} ] [.{56}  ] ] ]

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]